# Why does Fubini's theorem not apply in this example?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$ and $g(x,y)=\text{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}$ ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function )

We have $$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dy dx = 1/2 = -\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dy dx$$ 
and $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty g(x,y) dy dx = -\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty g(x,y) dx dy=-1$$

Why doesn't Fubini theorem  apply? For the first one, I think it's because of the pole at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ for $f(x,y)$. So that $f$ fails to be in $L^1 (\mathbb{R}^2)$. I'm not too sure about the second one.

Comment: Have you checked the conditions of Fubini's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "fail"?  Are you asking why we can't apply Fubini's theorem, or what's the reason of the failure of the conclusion?

A version of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem states that if $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function, then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) d(x,y)$ may be computed as an interated integral (i.e., $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx )dy$) if one of the two conditions hold:

1) $f(x,y) \ge 0$ everywhere;

2) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x,y)| d(x,y) < \infty$

Combining 1) and 2), we see that we need that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x,y)| dx dy < \infty$

So to show that Fubini's theorem cannot be applied, you need to show that...